# Store json array in the api controller -laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm a little bit confused to how I can store data in my api controller,

My json looks like this:

```json
[
  { a: 1 },
  { a: 2 }
]
```

I have my rules

```php
$rules = [
    '*.a' => 'required',
];
```

I have my validation

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    $error = $validator->messages()->toJson();
        
    return response($error, 200);
}
```

and now there's my "problem": I would like to make a cleaner code.

My old option was pass the request->all() to a variable , json decode the contenent and make a foreach cycle to store data as here:

```php
foreach ($datas as $data) {
    $data = new rawData([
        'a' => $data->a,
    ]);
    
    $newrawData->save();
}
```

can I do a cleaner thing?? and How?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your validation logic in a custom form request validator.
First, create the validator
`php artisan make:request ExampleRequest`

You can find the newly created a new class in `app/Http/Requests/ExampleRequest.php` and you can add your rules as follows

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ExampleRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            '*.a' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

Now your controller method/action will not be executed unless the request passes the validation rules. you can use it in your controller method as follows:
In `app/Http/Controllers/ExampleController.php`

```php
public function store(ExampleRequest $request)
{
  // Your normal code.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that looks quite good. There is only one small thing I would have done differently. But it's a matter of taste.

```
foreach ($datas as $data) {
    rawData::create($data->toArray());
}
```

And you can you use the request object directly to validate. or you implement an custom Request Object what you pass as parameter in your function.

```
$request->validate([
    '*.a' => 'required',
 ]);
```